# Complete Set-Cauchy Sequence

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Consider $(\Re ^{2},\left \| \cdot \right \|)$ with $\left \| x_{1}^{2}, x_{2}^{2} \right \| = \sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}$.

Is the set $\{(x_{1} ,x_{2})\in \Re ^{2} \mid x_{1}\neq 0 \text{ and } x_{2}=1/x_{1} \}$ complete?

Now I know for a set to be complete all cauchy sequence in the set must be convergent. I need help with the identification of the cauchy in the set. I suspect that the only cauchy sequences in the set are either constant sequences or the sequences which eventually become constant i.e. with a constant tail. If that's the case then we can show the set is complete. Am I correct?

Comment: In future, you can enclose LaTeX commands in dollar signs `$...$` to display it properly.

Comment: Thank @JordanMitchellBarrett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+\frac 1n , \frac 1 {1+\frac  1n})$ is a counter-example to your claim.

Let $(a_n,b_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then $a_nb_n=1$ for all $n$. Also the sequence is Cauchy in $\mathbb R^{2}$ (which is complete) so $(a_n,b_n)$ converges to some point $(a,b)$ in the plane. This gives $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$. Take limits in $a_nb_n=1$ to see that $ab=1$. Now check that $(a,b) $ belongs to the given set and $(a_n,b_n)$ converges to $(a,b)$. Since every Cauchy sequence in the set converges the set is complete.

Comment: I see your point. What is your verdict on the overall question then? Is the set complete? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, it is complete. That is exactly what I proved.